# Ext.Direct functions available within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, extjs-mvc, ext-direct

I have implemented Ext.Direct to return data to a Store however the directFn methods are not available within the javascript.

api.php returns
 `var Ext = Ext || {}; Ext.REMOTING_API = {"url":"php/api/router.php","type":"remoting","actions":{"RaStatuses":[{"name":"get_ra_statuses","len":1}]}};`

router.php returns
 `{"type":"rpc","tid":1,"action":"RaStatuses","method":"get_ra_statuses","result":[{"ra_no":"2"},{"ra_no":"4"},{"ra_no":"6"},{"ra_no":"8"},{"ra_no":"10"}]}`

...and successfully populates this store

```
Ext.define('CSM.store.ra.Statuses', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'CSM.model.ra.Status',
  proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    directFn: "RaStatuses.get_ra_statuses"
  },
  autoLoad: true
});
```

However when I use this line from within a javascript function
`a = RaStatuses.get_ra_statuses();`

...I get
`'ReferenceError: RaStatuses is not defined'`

Have I misunderstood? Should Ext.Direct make this object available inside the js or was this wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0):

This now works (ExtJS 6.0.2). I amended api.php to return...

```
Ext.namespace('RPC');   
var Ext = Ext || {};
RPC.REMOTING_API = {
    "url": "php/api/router.php",
    "type": "remoting",
    "namespace": "RPC",
    "descriptor": "RPC.REMOTING_API",
    "actions": {
        "RaStatuses": [{
            "name": "get_ra_statuses",
            "len": 0
        }]
    }
};
Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(RPC.REMOTING_API);
```

This call now returns data

```
RPC.RaStatuses.get_ra_statuses();
```